# Schema for storing history table (i.e. audit trail) in Redis?

Tags: redis, schema

We have a system that tracks the review state of tickets. The tickets can transition through various states (waiting for a review, currently being reviewed, accepted, not accepted etc.). The transitions are triggered by user commands.

For each state change, we also need to store some metadata - e.g. timestamp, requesting user etc.

The most common queries we'll be running are:

- Listing all tickets, with the current state of each one
- Listing all of the tickets in a given state
- Getting the history of a ticket, with each state change and associated metadata

I'd like to give it a shot doing this in Redis (partly as a learning exercise for Redis).

There seems to be a fair amount of information online on doing history tables in relational databases, with example schemas. However, I'm not able to find much information on doing history tables/audit trails in Redis.

Firstly, are there particular reasons that I **wouldn't** want to use Redis for this?

Secondly, what sort of schema would I be looking at in Redis, to store the above information?

Thirdly, any particular Redis-specific techniques/commands I can use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check if the memory requirements is adequate for your infrastructure. That would be the main concern for choosing Redis.

For modeling this problem, you will have one hash for each ticket, one has for each user, one hash for each state change, and many sets for keeping the necessary references between those hashes. If you think you will go this route, I can give you an example with more detail.

I would suggest you take a look at [Ohm](http://ohm.keyvalue.org/), which is a lightweight tool for modeling this kind of problems.

Comment: I don't anticipate memory being an issue (I know, famous last words) - the number of "active" tickets being reviewed at any stage is rather small - probably on the order of 10-20 maximum. We're working from Python, so I guess we'd use Redisco, which is apparently a Python port- however, that doesn't appear to be very active. Yes, if you could give an example with more details, so I can understand it better and gauge whether it works, that would be awesome =) - do you need any more details about the use case?